# Using ctypes with jython

Tags: python, jython, ctypes

I have a trouble with using ctypes lib in my python script. Here is my code (found on the Internet):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from ctypes import *
    user32 = windll.user32
    kernel32 = windll.kernel32

    class RECT(Structure):
        _fields_ = [
            ("left", c_ulong),
            ("top", c_ulong),
            ("right", c_ulong),
            ("bottom", c_ulong)];

    class GUITHREADINFO(Structure):
        _fields_ = [
        ("cbSize", c_ulong),
        ("flags", c_ulong),
        ("hwndActive", c_ulong),
        ("hwndFocus", c_ulong),
        ("hwndCapture", c_ulong),
        ("hwndMenuOwner", c_ulong),
        ("hwndMoveSize", c_ulong),
        ("hwndCaret", c_ulong),
        ("rcCaret", RECT)
        ]

    def moveCursorInCurrentWindow(x, y):
        # Find the focussed window.
        guiThreadInfo = GUITHREADINFO(cbSize=sizeof(GUITHREADINFO))
        user32.GetGUIThreadInfo(0, byref(guiThreadInfo))
        focussedWindow = guiThreadInfo.hwndFocus

        # Find the screen position of the window.
        windowRect = RECT()
        user32.GetWindowRect(focussedWindow, byref(windowRect))

        # Finally, move the cursor relative to the window.
        user32.SetCursorPos(windowRect.left + x, windowRect.top + y)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Quick test.
        moveCursorInCurrentWindow(100, 100)
```

The first problem was that python couldn't find the ctypes so i copied the files downloaded from the project site to

```
netbeans\6.9\jython-2.5.1\Lib\
```

(yep, im using netbeans) and then it shows this error:

```
>    from ctypes import *
>  File "C:\Users\k\.netbeans\6.9\jython-2.5.1\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
>    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
```

Just like the init file has some errors o_O Help guys!
Greetings, Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jython doesn't yet have full support for ctypes: http://bugs.jython.org/issue1328

You can't simply take the ctypes library compiled for CPython, and plug it into Jython.

Comment: For the record, `ctypes` support seems to be much better now, in the Jython 2.7 beta.

Answer (score 7):

`ctypes` in Jython experimental and not complete.

From the jython-users mailing list in a thread titled "[ctypes in Jython](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=AANLkTikZpn1%2Bkbjd-0z1-sBd%2BGf7BQSLCcD7tj%2B%2BTC3k%40mail.gmail.com&forum_name=jython-users)" Jim Baker (a Jython committer) wrote on November 17, 2010:

> There's some experimental support for
>   ctypes in 2.5.2 [the current version], but it's really more
>   of a placeholder at this point.

He then suggests these work arounds:

> I do recommend JNA if you can modify
>   your ctypes code. JNA is pretty close
>   to ctypes - JNA's API apparently was
>   significantly influenced by ctypes!
>   JNA also seems to work well with
>   Jython.
>
> The other option is to use something
>   like execnet. For execnet
>   specifically: it allows you to pair
>   Jython with CPython, and it does seem
>   to work well. But its GPL license
>   makes it a non starter for many
>   people. There are other choices out
>   there too.

Further on in the same thread we have this confirming assessment:

> I tried the ctypes module in 2.5.2rc2
>   recently, and found that: 1) There's
>   no ctypes.util.find_library yet 2)
>   ctypes.Structure doesn't support
>   non-scalar types yet
>
> So I agree with the "more of a
>   placeholder" assessment.  Still, it's
>   exciting to see it getting started.

Answer (score 3):

ctypes is not supported in Jython 2.5.1. There has been some experimental support added in 2.5.2, but it's certainly nowhere near complete. Maybe you'll have better luck using [JNA](http://jna.java.net/) with Jython instead. There's a short tutorial [here](http://www.flester.com/blog/2009/02/21/java-jna-jythonjruby-the-sweet-spot).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thx dudes! I just reconfig my NetBeans, now its using cPython. Everything works. I just had to changed the line
`user32.SetCursorPos(windowRect.left + x, windowRect.top + y)` to:
`user32.SetCursorPos(c_ulong(windowRect.left + x), c_ulong(windowRect.left + y))`