# Ctypes support in Jython

Tags: java, python, jython

I'm fairly new to Java and python. I have few python scripts which I need to call from Java application. Currently I'm using Jython 2.7 beta 3 version for doing this. My python script is using methods from Ctypes(create_string_buffer). When I run this script from Java it throws the following error.

'module' object has no attribute 'create_string_buffer'

my java code is below:

```
import org.python.core.PyInstance;  
import org.python.core.PyObject;
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;  
import org.python.core.PyString;


public class Sample  
{  

   PythonInterpreter interpreter = null;  


   public Sample()  
   {  
      PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(),  
                                   System.getProperties(), new String[0]);  

      this.interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();  
   }  

   void execfile( final String fileName )  
   {  
      this.interpreter.execfile(fileName);  
   } 

   void eval( final String className, final String opts )  
   {  
       this.interpreter.eval(className + "(" + opts + ")");    
   } 

   PyInstance createClass( final String className, final String opts )  
   {  
      return (PyInstance) this.interpreter.eval(className + "(" + opts + ")");  
   }  

   public static void main( String gargs[] )  
   {  
      Sample ie = new Sample();  

      ie.execfile("C:/Users/trail.py");   

   }  
}
```

Please let me know where Im going wrong or if Im missing something wrong.

Comment: Basically, trail.py is a script which talks to a hardware and returns some information. I cant disclose this because of confidentiality issues. I don't have access to modify the scripts either. The script is using lot of Ctypes functionalities and other native libraries. My Java application need to run this script and use the output. I did lot of googling lately but couldn't find a suitable way for this. Currently, I ended up using Runtime.getRuntime().exec() to run the script but this doesn't seems to be an ideal approach. Can anyone help me with the best approach in this scenario?

Comment: @mzjn When I run the following python script from java using Jython I get this error:                                            import ctypes

p=ctypes.create_string_buffer('Hello')
print p.value

Please Let me know if you need any more information. Im not able to solve this with any approach.

Comment: Suggestion: edit the question instead of adding information in comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186670/using-ctypes-with-jython

Answer (score 0):

The ctypes module in CPython (2.7) defines a `create_string_buffer` function. The ctypes module in Jython (2.7 beta 3) does not.

I don't really know more than this, but it seems reasonable to conclude that support for ctypes in Jython is incomplete. See also:

- http://bugs.jython.org/issue2148
- http://fwierzbicki.blogspot.se/2014/08/jython-27-beta3-released.html (ctypes is mentioned in one of the comments)

Comment: Ok, so what is the best way to execute such python scripts from java?

Comment: I can't think of anything besides `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` that you already use.

Comment: The Java Scripting API might be an option. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/api.html.