# ImportError: cannot import name create_string_buffer

Tags: python, mule, jython, mulesoft

I'm using python script in mulesoft ,while importing a library the above error is occuring?
Any help would be much appreciated . Below is the error I get:

Message               : ImportError: cannot import name create_string_buffer in  at line number 2

Element               : pythondemoFlow/processors/2/processors/1 @ pythondemo:pythondemo.xml:27 (Execute)

Comment: Please share the script component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to import ctypes into your script, it will not work. Python support in Mule depends on the Jython implementation which doesn't really supports ctypes. See [Using ctypes with jython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186670/using-ctypes-with-jython) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the `python.path` property?
As explained [here](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-use-Python-external-modules) it looks like this is what you might be missing.

> ##### In Cloudhub
>
> Define the Cloudhub property for **python.path** to `/opt/mule/mule-CURRENT/apps/<APPNAME>/classes` in the application settings.
>
> ##### On Premise
>
> Set the property by adding it to the wrapper.conf file.
> For example:
> wrapper.java.additional.=-Dpython.path=/path/to/your/libraries